# Is it possible to configure both Latency and Failover routing for a same low lever domain from a different high level domain?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I have 2 high level domains "abc.domain" and "def.domain" and there are 2 low level domains namely "app.us1.domain" and "app.us2.domain".

Is the following configuration possible in AWS Route53?

```
CNAME record 1: abc.domain -> app.us1.domain : Failover routing(Primary)
CNAME record 2: abc.domain -> app.us2.domain : Failover routing(Secondary)
CNAME record 3: def.domain -> app.us1.domain : Latency routing(region-1)
CNAME record 4: def.domain -> app.us2.domain : Latency routing(region-2)
```

Comment: You can try making it and see how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is possible.  You can only use one routing type at a single domain name and type pair, but as you are using two different domain names in your example, that should work fine.

If you find you need to logically combine routing types, e.g. to configure latency based routing with failover at each location, you can do that by creating multiple domain names and aliasing between them, e.g.

```
www.example.com.  region=us-east-1  A ALIAS www-us.example.com.
www.example.com.  region=eu-west-1  A ALIAS www-eu.example.com.
www.example.com.  region=ap-northeast-1 A ALIAS www-jp.example.com.

www-us.example.com.  PRIMARY  A 10.1.2.3
www-us.example.com.  SECONDARY A  10.1.2.4

www-eu.example.com.  PRIMARY  A 10.2.2.3
www-eu.example.com.  SECONDARY A  10.2.2.4

www-jp.example.com.  PRIMARY  A  10.3.2.3
www-jp.example.com.  SECONDARY A 10.3.2.4
```